# How to prevent one child element from scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to prevent scaling #chart while scaling .container?

I want to scale all content (.container) except one div (#chart) while the user resizes the browser window. To this div, I have imported a chart from apexcharts.js and it isn't working properly because of scaling this element. So I want to omit to scale this particular div to fit in all the free space (it is a responsive chart). I have no idea how to do this...

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => resizeWindow());

const resizeWindow = () => {
   const {innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height} = window;
  
   if(width < 768) {
      const scale = height/PANEL_HEIGHT;
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(SCALE_PROPERTY, scale);

      return;
   }
   else {
   const scale = Math.min(width/PANEL_WIDTH, height/PANEL_HEIGHT);
   document.documentElement.style.setProperty(SCALE_PROPERTY, scale);
   }
}
```

```css
:root {
   --scale-value: 1;
}
.panel {
   height: 1000px;
   width: 1600px;
   position: absolute;
   transform: scale(calc(var(--scale-value) * 0.9));
   transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `transform` for non-animation purposes causes blur and artifacts, most scaling should be done with relative units such as `em` (relative to font size). You can then just express the font size with a `calc`/`clamp` formula using units like `vw`.
Is your chart in a grid or a flex?

Comment: Of course I know about em, vw e.t.c but i wanted to end this project quickly and not to play with responsive stuff (mostly because it is CMS). And thats why I used scaling whole content. Unfortuneltly the problem is chart which can't be scaled...

Comment: And this chart is in flex